# Map binding of generic factories

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice, factory

Suppose we have a couple of `Shape` implementations. Each implementation is created by a `ShapeFactory` from a corresponding `ShapeConfig`.

```java
interface Shape {}

class Circle implements Shape {}
class Square implements Shape {}
...

-----

abstract class ShapeConfig {
    abstract String getName();
}

class CircleConfig extends ShapeConfig {}
class SquareConfig extends ShapeConfig {}
...

-----

interface ShapeFactory<C extends ShapeConfig> {
    Shape create(C config);
}

class CircleConfig implements ShapeFactory<CircleConfig> {}
class SquareConfig implements ShapeFactory<SquareConfig> {}
...
```

Given a set of `ShapeConfig` objects, I want to construct a map binding of `Shape` objects by their configured name:

```java
class ShapeModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        ShapeFactory<CircleConfig> circleFactory = new CircleFactory();
        ShapeFactory<SquareConfig> squareFactory = new SquareFactory();
        // ...

        MapBinder<String, Shape> shapesByName = newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, Shape.class);

        for (ShapeConfig config : getShapeConfigs()) {
            if (config instanceof CircleConfig) {
                Shape shape = circleFactory.create((CircleConfig) config);
                shapesByName.addBinding(config.getName()).toInstance(shape);
                continue;
            }
            if (config instanceof SquareConfig) {
                Shape shape = squareFactory.create((SquareConfig) config);
                shapesByName.addBinding(config.getName()).toInstance(shape);
                continue;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the map binder is pretty much useless but I hope it clarifies my intent. What would a proper solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looks like you:

- Have static Shape Configs (at load time)
- Are attempting to use `Shape circle = shapes.get("circle");` returning effectively a singleton `Circle`.

Which if you want, seems pretty spot on.  But if you wanted to dynamically generate `Shape`(s) based on runtime `ShapeConfig`(s) then you might want to do something like:

```
MapBinder<ShapeConfig, ShapeFactory> shapeFactories = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), ShapeConfig.class, ShapeFactory.class);
shapeFactories.addBinding(CircleConfig.class, CircleFactory.class);
shapeFactories.addBinding(SquareConfig.class, SquareFactory.class);
// etc.
```

Which would then be used as:

```
public class ShapeManager {
  @Inject Map<ShapeConfig, ShapeFactory> factories;

  public <T implements ShapeConfig, R implements Shape> R manage(T config) {
    Shape shape = factories.get(config.class).create(config);
    // do stuff?
    return shape;
  }
}
```

which you can then call how you like:

```
Shape shape = manager.manage(new CircleConfig(...));
// shape should be a Circle
```